# JDBC-ODBC connectivity

Tags: jdbc

```
   import java.sql.*;

   public class QBreaker
   {
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {  
       Connection conn = null;
       String driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
       String url="jdbc:odbc:huss";
       try
       {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","admin123");
        System.out.println("Connection is created");
        Statement db_statement=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=db_statement.executeQuery("select * from Details");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.print("ID: "+rs.getInt("Id"));
            System.out.print("\tBalance: "+rs.getString("Bal"));
        }
        conn.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        System.out.println(e);
       }
   }
```

}

This is my code to connect to the database.
i have created the odbc driver n followed all the required steps in dat.
but still while running the i got this exception:

```
Connection is created
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Details'.
```

Process completed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such table or view named `Details` exists. Please verify the database.

Answer (score 0):

u create Data source ? , if u not created it can u go to control panel in windows then  Administrative Tools then Data Sources (ODBC) .